# Convertir expresión regular js a expresión regular bash

Tags: regex, bash

Necesito obtener el codigo de un objeto json string, para ello en js uso la siguiente expresion regular `objetoString.replace(/(.*)("codigo":")(((.)*?)"{1,})(.*)/,"$3")`. Ahora debo utilizarla en una función sh, pero no sé cómo hacer la transformación a ese lenguaje.

```
obtenerObjeto(){
     local objeto="{
              \"x1\":\"1\",
              \"x2\":\"2\",
              \"x3\":\"3\",
              \"codigo\":\"00012345678\",
              \"x4\":\"4\",
              \"x5\":\"5\"
             }"
     echo "$objeto"
}

echo "Fin obtencion codigo objeto">objeto.log
objetoString=$(obtenerObjeto)
codigo=$objetoString | sed -e #Expresion regular para sh
echo "codigo objeto: $codigo">>objeto.log
echo "Fin obtencion codigo objeto">>objeto.log
```

Intenté  con la siguiente forma, pero falla: `echo $objetoString | sed 's/\(\.*\)\("codigo":"\)\(\(\(\.\)*?\)"\{1,\}\)\(\.*\)/\3'`

Este es el código que utilizo en javascript:

```
var object = {
               x1: "1",
               x2: "2",
               x3: "3",
               codigo: "00012345678",
               x4: "4",
               x5: "5"
             };
var objetoString  = JSON.stringify(object);
console.log(objetoString.replace(/(.*)("codigo":")(((.)*?)"{1,})(.*)/,"$3"));
```

Por favor su ayuda para resolver esto, si hay algo que no se entienda, no tengo problemas en explicar

Comment: Una observación: Objeto no es igual a JSON. O tienes un JSON o tienes un Objeto, son cosas totalmente diferentes. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras también existen los json object, en español sería objeto json, por ende, no entiendo a qué va tu observación. Saludos

Comment: No, no existen los JSON Objects. Exite [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) y existe [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object), pero [no existe JSON Object](http://www.fizerkhan.com/blog/posts/JSON-is-not-Javascript-Object.html). Mi observación es porque inicias tu pregunta con: *Necesito obtener el codigo de un objeto json string*. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras entonces tú dices que la documentación de w3schools es incorrecta https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Answer (score 1):

Hola te comento que hace un par de semanas estuve investigando al respecto y púde resolver con lo siguiente:

```sh
new_key="new_key"
new_value="new value"
sed -i "s/codigo:\(.*\)/${new_key}: '${new_value}', /g" file.json
```

No sé que valores en especifíco necesitas cambiar de la línea pero ahí solo lo configuras en las variables respectivas.

el resultado el sed tal y como está sería:

```
{
    "x1":"1",
    "x2":"2",
    "x3":"3",
    "new_key":"new value",
    "x4":"4",
    "x5":"5"
}
```

Te explico, la primera parte de la expresión es el patrón a buscar:

```
"s/codigo:\(.*\)/
```

La segunda parte es el valor a sustituir:

```
${new_key}: '${new_value}', /g"
```

Y listo eso es todo.

Lamentablemente mi solución fue sustituida por una librería más potente de trabajo con json en Python, pero bueno a tí te servirá de seguro.

Trata de adaptarlo a tu necesidad.

Comment: intenté usar tu código, pero no sirvió para lo que necesitaba. Más abajo responderé con la solución que encontré.

Comment: Lo importante es que resolviste tu problema :) saludos.

Answer (score 0):

encontré una solución a mi problema, quizás no es al forma más elegante, pero satisface mi necesidad.

Necesitaba obtener el valor de la propiedad código desde el string que respresentaba un json object. Acá les dejo la solución:

```
obtenerObjeto(){
 local objeto="{
          \"x1\":\"1\",
          \"x2\":\"2\",
          \"x3\":\"3\",
          \"codigo\":\"00012345678\",
          \"x4\":\"4\",
          \"x5\":\"5\"
         }"
 echo "$objeto"
}

echo "Inicio obtencion codigo objeto">objeto.log
objetoString=$(obtenerObjeto)
codigo="${objetoString#*codigo\":\"}";
codigo="${codigo%%\"*}";
echo "codigo objeto: $codigo">>objeto.log #Imprime codigo objeto: 00012345678
echo "Fin obtencion codigo objeto">>objeto.log
```

Para esto me base en la documentación `${var#Pattern}, ${var##Pattern}` y `${var%Pattern}, ${var%%Pattern}` contenida en la siguiente página: [Parameter Substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

De todas formas quedo a la espera de una solución más robusta.